# Autocomplete in cascading textboxes with MVC 3 Razor and JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, razor, autocomplete

I'm trying to display autocompleted city names in a textbox using **JQuery Autocomplete**, from a zipcode textbox to be filled by the user.

City textbox autocompletion must be triggered by **focus on the control**. But I still have to press the down key to display autocompleted cities. 
Moreover, if I change the value in the postal code textbox, autocompletion will first display the last matched city.
Anyone has an idea what I should do to solve these issues?

Here's my code.
First, the View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#PostalCode').blur(function () {
        $.getJSON("http://xxxxxxxxx/Cities/GetCities", { strPostalCode: $('#PostalCode').val() }, function (data) {
            $("#autocompCities").autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: data
            }).focus(function () {
                $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PostalCode)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City, new { id = "autocompCities" })
```

and then, in my controller:

```
public JsonResult GetCities(string strPostalCode)
{
//retrieving data
var cities = from city in allCities
                     where city.Id == strPostalCode
                     select city.Name;

        return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

FYI, I solved my precedent issue (JSONResult function was never called) by modifying the url in the getJSON function, as i thought the route generated by using "Url.Action" did not match the route mapped in my global.asax file.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using the 'source' option incorrectly.

According to the documentation at: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp
if you click on the view source link, you can see that the source takes the form:

```
source: function(request, response) { ... }
```

and within that function, response is called with the data for the autocomplete as its parameter as such

```
data = [];
response(data);
```

response() is used for typical autocomplete functionality where a drop down shows results, which is not exactly what it seems that you're looking for.

Another problem with your jquery is that you have the autocompCities being both the target for update and the autocomplete widget, which is contrary to the functionality that you said you wanted.  You'd want to make the Zip Code field to be the autocomplete widget, but suppress default behavior and update autocompCities upon ajax success.

Comment: Thank you for your help, as you've noticed i'm a beginner in jquery! I'll update my code and post the result below if my problem remains!

Comment: I've updated with my last changes and with additional explanations.